# How to change a UINavigation Bar Fonts

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uinavigationbar, uifont

I am using this code to change the navigation bar color and font. How do i make the font thin? I tried adding a font family name, but the app crashed. Please answer in swift.

```
nav?.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(20)]
```

Answer (score 2):

use this code :

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "CaviarDreams", size: 20)!]
let colorDict: NSDictionary = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = colorDict
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at your own code, **bold** is the opposite to thin.

When you state `UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(20)]` you're telling UIKit to use the default Font with a **thick** format.

**UPDATE:**

Use one of these functions instead:

```
UIFont.systemFontOfSize(fontSize: CGFloat, weight: CGFloat)
UIFont.systemFontOfSize(fontSize: CGFloat)
```